# I want to search for string in a file using ansible

Tags: ansible

```
- name: extract a word
            ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
                    path: /file/to/path/file.log
                    regexp: '^nodeagent stopped: (.*)'
                    line: 'nodeagent stopped'
            register: extracted
          - debug:
                  msg: 'The extracted word is {{ extracted.matched }}'
```

with the above code snippet I am trying to search for this "nodeagent stopped" in a file but I get this error:

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'matched'

The error appears to be in '/home/a239255/testing/test-playbook/restart-test3.yml': line 10, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be: 

           register: extracted
      - debug:
        ^ here
"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is almost no information and further description what you try to achieve. I assume you are looking for how to monitor if a certain service or process is up and running?

Answer (score 1):

Please take note that the module [`lineinfile` module (is to) Manage lines in text files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) and therefore not the appropriate approach for (live) log file monitoring (annot.: unfortunately there is almost no information and further description).

Also, the `lineinfile` module do not maintain own unique [Return Values except the common ones](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html). Therefore [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) will not provide the file content or even parts of it.

What you was probably trying to do was something like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    SEARCH_STRING: "nodeagent stopped"
    SEARCH_FILE: "test.log"

  tasks:

  - name: Search for string
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ SEARCH_FILE }}"
      regexp: '^{{ SEARCH_STRING }}: (.*)'
      line: "SEARCH_STRING FOUND"
      state: present
    register: result
    # Since it is a reporting task
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: "'line replaced' in result.msg" # as it means SEARCH_STRING FOUND
    check_mode: true # to prevent changes and do a dry-run only

  - name: Show result, if not found
    debug:
      var: result
    when: "'line added' in result.msg" # as it means SEARCH_STRING NOT FOUND
```

If you like to extract a specific string from a static (log) file you could use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Read log file
    slurp:
      src: test.log
    register: log

  - name: Show log file
    debug:
      msg: "{{ log['content'] | b64decode }}"

  - name: Show first result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ log['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('nodeagent stopped') | first }}"
```

This was taken from a

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to pull a specific string out of the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099369/6771046)

but for different use case.

Please notice that by using the `slurp` module you are going to transfer the whole file from the Remote Node to the Control Node over the network just to process it and looking up a string. For log files these are usually several MB. Whereby you probably are only interested in the information if the file on the Remote Node contains a certain string and therefore would only need to transfer that kind of information, `true` or `false`.

---

This means the above approach should be avoided and an other approach will fit better. Do the processing, searching the string on the Remote Node, in example and in Bash

```sh
grep 'not found' test.log; echo $?
1
grep 'nodeagent stopped' test.log; echo $?
nodeagent stopped: 0
nodeagent stopped: 1
0
```

so an Ansible a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    SEARCH_STRING: "nodeagent stopped"
    SEARCH_FILE: "test.log"

  tasks:

  - name: Search for string in file
    command:
      cmd: "grep '{{ SEARCH_STRING }}' {{ SEARCH_FILE }}"
    register: result
    # Since it is a reporting task
    # which needs to deliver a result in any case
    failed_when: result.rc != 0 and result.rc != 1
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false
```

You can than just check the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#return-values) and Return Code (`rc`) of `0` or `1` and if the string was contained or not.

```yaml
  - name: Show result, if any
    debug:
      var: result.stdout_lines
    when: result.rc == 0
```

---

If you like to manage an IBM WebSphere application you could have a look into specific Custom Modules for, in example and since there seems to be already some, [Ansible WebSphere](https://github.com/amimof/ansible-websphere)

> *A set of Ansible modules that lets you manage IBM packages and WebSphere resources*

More and other playbook examples can be find if searching how to start, stop or check, server nodeagents.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

> The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'matched'

The dictionary *extracted* has no attribute *matched*. Take a look at the dictionary and fix it.

---

Q: ***"Search for this `"nodeagent stopped"` in a file."***

A: For example, given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file.log 
nodeagent started: 0
nodeagent stopped: 0
nodeagent started: 1
nodeagent stopped: 1
```

Read the file, split the lines, and [*search*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) for the pattern

```yaml
    - name: Read the file
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: /tmp/file.log
      register: file_log
```

Declare the variable

```yaml
  matched: "{{ file_log.content|b64decode|split('\n')|
               select('search', 'nodeagent stopped') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  matched:
  - 'nodeagent stopped: 0'
  - 'nodeagent stopped: 1'
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    error: {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined
    variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute
    'matched'\n\nThe error appears to be in
    '/home/a239255/testing/test-playbook/restart-test3.yml': line 10,
    column 13, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
    exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n
    register: extracted\n - debug:\n ^ here\n"}
    
    # Search for this "nodeagent stopped" in a file
    matched: "{{ file_log.content|b64decode|split('\n')|
                 select('search', 'nodeagent stopped') }}"

  tasks:

#    - name: extract a word
#      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
#        path: /file/to/path/file.log
#        regexp: '^nodeagent stopped: (.*)'
#        line: 'nodeagent stopped'
#      register: extracted
#    - debug:
#        msg: 'The extracted word is {{ extracted.matched }}'
    - debug:
        var: error

    - name: Read the file
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
        src: /tmp/file.log
      register: file_log

    - debug:
        var: file_log.content|b64decode

    - debug:
        var: matched
```